# How can we prove this?

Tags: improper-integrals, laplace-transform

[image]
Proving this using Laplace Transform

Answer (score 0):

Ok ok
I was confused about the exponential term.

Finding the laplace and putting s=0 will do.
Pardon.
How to delete this question?[image]

Comment: You should differentiate the laplace tranform wrt $s$ and then take a much easier transform

Comment: also, if you weren't kidding re deletion, there should be a button at the bottom of your post

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen which says flag

Comment: It's to the left of flag on mine, but not sure how it works, never deleted a question (though plenty of answers). Of course now that your work's up and it appears you've done it right, you could also just opt to accept the answer instead.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen you have reputation above 1000 maybe. Yeah, accepting it.